# Perform WHERE != in CodeIgniter Activerecord

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

How can I perform `WHERE column != 100001` in CodeIgniter Activerecord? Sorry, but I cannot find any sources about this.

My Query is

```
$this->db->select('friend, username, fullname, profile_pic')
                        ->from('friends')
                        ->join('user_info', 'user_info.id = friend')
                        ->where('user', $my->id)
                        ->where('status', '1')
                        ->get()->result_object();
```

I want to add `->where('friend' != 10001)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember that the second paramter is the value:

```
->where('friends.friend !=', 10001)
```

And yes, this is well documented on the [active record manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

Its in the **`Custom key/value method:`** part of the **`->where()`** method.

Comment: Thanks..It works. Why on earth I never think of that?

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 ways to do that, first declare your syntax in variable.. here is the code

```
$where = "user='".$my->id."' AND status='1' AND friend !=10001";

$this->db->where($where);
```

Or use this

```
$this->db->where('friend !=', 10001);
```